# checking if 2 emails were communicate with each other

Tags: email, smtp

Maybe with SMTP servers edited?

Comment: The context of the question is unclear. What kind of access has the one who wants the information? Access to the mail box of one of the communication partners? To logs of the involved mail servers? ...

Comment: Yes, the email server logs will show that 2 email ***addresses*** had sent emails to each other.

Comment: let's say I don't have access to either of the emails. I know that the question is not completely clear because the concept is that:
I work as a tech advisor to law firm and we have a case that someone claims that with given email address he can check if this address communicate ever with other company's emails addresses (way to check if it's in this company whitelist or black list). as far as I Know there is no way to check that or create any smtp logs without login to one of the addresses. Am I right?

Comment: whitelist/blacklist? How is this relevant? How does one check this? You've been asking this question different ways for a couple weeks. It's not any clearer... No way to create smtp logs without logging into a specific *address*? What do you mean?

Comment: You orginally say that "I'm writing an app that tries to check if an email address is already known by a company or not" -- now you say "I work as a tech advisor to law firm". What is actually going on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> someone claims that with given email address he can check if this address
> communicate ever with other company's emails addresses

Without access to any part of the communication (mails, mail server ...) this is not possible

> ​(way to check if it's in this company whitelist or black list)

Checking white and blacklist is mainly unrelated to checking if two parties have ever communicated with each other. While in some setups partners from established communications might be white listed, this is not a standard setup. And even if they are white listed there might be additional requirements for the white listing, like specific source IP addresses. Similar it will not blacklist all other recipients.

The nearest which comes to what the claim might be here is an anti-spam technology called [Greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting_(email)) which is employed by some (but not all) mail servers. It will return temporary errors for previously unseen combinations of sender and recipient in the hope that proper mail servers will retry while spammer botnets will not. But Greylisting usually not only takes the senders email in account but also the senders IP address. This means it cannot be used to query the established communication relations from arbitrary IP addresses. Moreover it sometimes is used to whitelist a complete sender domain, not a single sender.